# RegEx for the following string

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex for an ID with the following rules:

1. Starts with A-Z, one or more times. (Main ID, mi)
2. Followed with an optional dash. (delimiter)
3. Followed with 0-9, one or more times. (Sub ID, si)
4. Followed with an optional dash or dot. (delimiter)
5. Followed with an optional a-z or 0-9, one or more times. (Main category, mc)
6. Followed with an optional dash or dot. (delimiter)
7. Followed with an optional a-z or 0-9, one or more times. (Sub category, sc)

The delimiters **can be** omitted if the ID is alternating alpha and numeric (A-01a1, A1.a.1). Delimiters is **required** if succeeding parts are both alpha or both numeric (A-1.1a, A1.2.3, A1a.a).

Here is what I have:

```
(?P<mi>[A-Z]+)-?(?P<si>[0-9]+)[\-\.]?(?P<mc>[a-z0-9])*[\-\.]?(?P<sc>[a-z0-9])*
```

Here is the result when I tried it:

```
ID      mi  si  mc  sc
A1      A   1
A001    A   001
AB-01   AB  01
A1aa    A   1   a      <<<<< mc=aa
A-01a1  A   01  1      <<<<< mc=a sc=1
A-1.1a  A   1   a      <<<<< mc=1 sc=a
A1.a1   A   1   1      <<<<< mc=a sc=1
A1.a.1  A   1   a   1
A1.2.3  A   1   2   3
A1a.a   A   1   a   a
```

Comment: Which language are you using?  Regex facilities are different in different languages (though this definitely looks like a PCRE variant).

Comment: I just use RegEx101.com

Comment: It wants to know too.  Out of the box the PCRE variant seems to be selected, but you can click along the left edge to make it use JS or Python dialects.  There are obviously many more which it doesn't support.

Comment: PCRE (default I guess). I did not know that it has JS and Python variant on the left side. I just open that site for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

`(?<=&|^)xxx=true^(?P<MainID>[a-z]+)-?(?<SubID>[0-9]+)(?:[-.]?(?P<MainCategory>(?<=[-.])[a-z0-9]+(?=[-.\s])|[a-z]+|[0-9]+))?(?:[-.]?(?P<SubCategory>(?<=[-.])[a-z0-9]+(?=[-.\s])|[a-z]+|[0-9]+))?`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

The regex does the following:

- Starts with A-Z, one or more times. (Main ID, mi)
- Followed with an optional dash. (delimiter)
- Followed with 0-9, one or more times. (Sub ID, si)
- Followed with an optional dash or dot. (delimiter)
- Followed with an optional a-z or 0-9, one or more times. (Main category, mc)
- Followed with an optional dash or dot. (delimiter)
- Followed with an optional a-z or 0-9, one or more times. (Sub category, sc)
- If a group of text is surrounded by delimiters or the end of the string then the characters are allowed to alternate between letters and numbers for the same capture group
- If the string is not surrounded by delimiters then the only letters or numbers are allowed to be captured

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/uH7zF3/1

**Sample text**

```
ID      mi  si  mc  sc
A1      A   1
A001    A   001
AB-01   AB  01
A1aa    A   1   a      <<<<< mc=aa
A-01a1  A   01  1      <<<<< mc=a sc=1
A-1.1a  A   1   a      <<<<< mc=1 sc=a
A1.a1   A   1   1      <<<<< mc=a sc=1
A1.a.1  A   1   a   1
A1.2.3  A   1   2   3
A1a.a   A   1   a   a
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
MainID  [24-25] `A`
SubID   [25-26] `1`

MATCH 2
MainID  [38-39] `A`
SubID   [39-42] `001`

MATCH 3
MainID  [54-56] `AB`
SubID   [57-59] `01`

MATCH 4
MainID  [69-70] `A`
SubID   [70-71] `1`
MainCategory    [71-73] `aa`

MATCH 5
MainID  [104-105]   `A`
SubID   [106-108]   `01`
MainCategory    [108-109]   `a`
SubCategory [109-110]   `1`

MATCH 6
MainID  [143-144]   `A`
SubID   [145-146]   `1`
MainCategory    [147-149]   `1a`

MATCH 7
MainID  [182-183]   `A`
SubID   [183-184]   `1`
MainCategory    [185-187]   `a1`

MATCH 8
MainID  [221-222]   `A`
SubID   [222-223]   `1`
MainCategory    [224-225]   `a`
SubCategory [226-227]   `1`

MATCH 9
MainID  [243-244]   `A`
SubID   [244-245]   `1`
MainCategory    [246-247]   `2`
SubCategory [248-249]   `3`

MATCH 10
MainID  [265-266]   `A`
SubID   [266-267]   `1`
MainCategory    [267-268]   `a`
SubCategory [269-270]   `a`
```

## Explanation

```
^ assert position at start of a line
(?P<MainID>[a-z]+) Named capturing group MainID
[a-z]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
-? matches the character - literally
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?<SubID>[0-9]+) Named capturing group SubID
[0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
(?:[-.]?(?P<MainCategory>(?<=[-.])[a-z0-9]+(?=[-.\s])|[a-z]+|[0-9]+))? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
[-.]? match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
-. a single character in the list -. literally
(?P<MainCategory>(?<=[-.])[a-z0-9]+(?=[-.\s])|[a-z]+|[0-9]+) Named capturing group MainCategory
1st Alternative: (?<=[-.])[a-z0-9]+(?=[-.\s])
(?<=[-.]) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched
[-.] match a single character present in the list below
-. a single character in the list -. literally
[a-z0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
(?=[-.\s]) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
[-.\s] match a single character present in the list below
-. a single character in the list -. literally
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
2nd Alternative: [a-z]+
[a-z]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
3rd Alternative: [0-9]+
[0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
(?:[-.]?(?P<SubCategory>(?<=[-.])[a-z0-9]+(?=[-.\s])|[a-z]+|[0-9]+))? Non-capturing group
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
[-.]? match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
-. a single character in the list -. literally
(?P<SubCategory>(?<=[-.])[a-z0-9]+(?=[-.\s])|[a-z]+|[0-9]+) Named capturing group SubCategory
1st Alternative: (?<=[-.])[a-z0-9]+(?=[-.\s])
(?<=[-.]) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched
[-.] match a single character present in the list below
-. a single character in the list -. literally
[a-z0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
(?=[-.\s]) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
[-.\s] match a single character present in the list below
-. a single character in the list -. literally
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
2nd Alternative: [a-z]+
[a-z]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)
3rd Alternative: [0-9]+
[0-9]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
```

Comment: It seems like fails only when on list but not if it is by itself

Comment: For `A-1-aa1` the `aa1` part should be the main category? In this https://regex101.com/r/uH7zF3/3 I modified the `(?=[-.\s])` to also test for the end of a string, so now they look like `(?=[-.\s]|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` in your expression should be relocated to the inside of your capture groups

Also you can remove the slashes inside the character case

```
(?P<mi>[A-Z]+)-?(?P<si>[0-9]+)[\-\.]?(?P<mc>[a-z0-9])*[\-\.]?(?P<sc>[a-z0-9])*
                               ^ ^                   ^ ^ ^                   ^
```

Should look like:

```
(?P<mi>[A-Z]+)-?(?P<si>[0-9]+)[-.]?(?P<mc>[a-z0-9]*)[-.]?(?P<sc>[a-z0-9]*)
```

Comment: fails at A-01a1, A-1-aa1

Answer (score 0):

I would use this one:

```
(?<mi>[A-Z]+)-?(?<si>[0-9]+)[-.]?(?<mc>[a-z0-9]*)[-.]?(?<sc>[a-z0-9]*)
```